# Find closest tuple from list of tuples - Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have list of tuples which contains latitudes and longitudes

```
list_of_tuples = [
 (48.383015375128444, 11.112193974456085), 
 (48.38301264157321, 11.112228110565772), 
 (48.383007738644274, 11.112256631732311), 
 (48.38300037666574, 11.112279943681244), 
 (48.382990265960615, 11.11229845213883), 
 (48.38297711685105, 11.112312562832122), 
 (48.382960639658386, 11.112322681489001), 
 (48.38294054470342, 11.112329213838153), 
 (48.38291654230646, 11.112332565609025)
]
```

Now I have another coordinate:

```
coordinate = 48.36720362305641, 11.112587917596102
```

and I want to know which is the closest tuple from above list to given `coordinate`

I tried:

`min(list_of_tuples, key=lambda c: (point[0]- coordinate[0])**2 + (point[1]-coordinate[1])**2)`

When using above code, I am always getting 1st tuple from the list.

Comment: I think the problem is the `lambda` expression, try this: `min(list_of_tuples, key=lambda c: (c[0]- coordinate[0])**2 + (c[1]-coordinate[1])**2)`

Answer (score 5):

You're not using your local variable in your lambda function, instead you reference a variable called `point` that is defined somewhere else.

```
min(list_of_tuples, key=lambda point: (point[0] - coordinate[0])**2 + (point[1] - coordinate[1])**2)
```

I renamend `c` to `point`, so your function still works and is verbose.